# How to retrieve unique key from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this error, which I think it can't read `unique key` from the `firebase` since I use `push()` function. It actually has 1 unique id from user and under it another generated by push function.

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -LX96YLmx5G_w8yEDTgi found on class
>   com.official.roomv1.Caller.Advertise
>       No setter/field for -LX95gJQNfc9sN81LY3_ found on class com.official.roomv1.Caller.Advertise
>       No setter/field for -LX95T40zIbRfCRmZpFo found on class com.official.roomv1.Caller.Advertise

This is for android apps. It can read other data that are not using unique key from `push()` function.

```
public DatabaseHelper() {
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Property");
}

public void readProperty(final DataStatus dataStatus){
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            property.clear();
            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot keyNode : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                keys.add(keyNode.getKey());
                Advertise advertise = keyNode.getValue(Advertise.class);
                property.add(advertise);
            }
            dataStatus.DataIsLoaded(property,keys);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Here's my current database test

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your JSON has two nested levels:

1. the UID
2. a push ID

So essentially you seems to have a list of properties for each user. That means that your code needs two loops: one for the users, and one for the properties for that user.

In code:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    property.clear();
    List<String> propertyKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        for (DataSnapshot propertySnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()){
            propertyKeys.add(propertySnapshot.getKey());
            Advertise advertise = propertySnapshot.getValue(Advertise.class);
            property.add(advertise);
        }
    }
    dataStatus.DataIsLoaded(property, propertyKeys);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where do you use **push()**. But from there you have to get your **push key.**

Here is the way how you can get the push key:

```
String pushID= reference.push().getKey();
```

And then, you do the update here :

```
reference.pushID.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { ..... }
```

You add the push ID, and you have the specific way to your data. Hope you understand.